# Equivalence relation and quotient set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I'm studying for a test and got stuck in one question regarding equivalence relations and quotient set. Here is the question:

> Let $F=\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> - Give an example of equivalence relation S in F such that $|F/S|=2^{\aleph}$
> - Give an example of equivalence relation S in F such that $|F/S|=\aleph$
> - Give an example of equivalence relation S in F such that $|F/S|$ is not $2^{\aleph},\aleph \ or \ 1$

I have no clue how to begin. I guess that an explanation of the first one will suffice.

Comment: That's a rather weird, to say the least, way to denote a group (I'm almost sure you meant *set* , right?) of functions...

Comment: And what do you call $\;\aleph\;$ to? Should it perhaps be $\;\aleph_0\;$ ?

Comment: True, should be a set. I meant $\aleph$, it is the continuity cardinality (same as C or $2^{\aleph_0}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Take any partition $\mathcal{F}_{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}$ of $F$ into $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ non-empty sets (e.g. $\{\{f\} \mid f \in F\}$).
- Take any partition $\mathcal{F}_{2^{\aleph_0}}$ of $F$ into $2^{\aleph_0}$ non-empty sets (e.g. split by $f(0)$, that is, take sets $A_x = \{ f \mid f(0) = x\}$).
- Take any partition $\mathcal{F}_{\aleph_0}$ of $F$ into ${\aleph_0}$ non-empty sets.
- Take any partition $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ of $F$ into $2$ non-empty sets.
- Define for $i \in \{2, \aleph_0, 2^{\aleph_0}, 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}\}$ relation $\sim_i$ as
  $$f \sim_{i} g \iff \exists A \in \mathcal{F}_i.\ f \in A \land g \in A.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$